# Animate CC HTML 5 - click on second button not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events, animate-cc

I'm just a beginner in Javascript, and I'm making simple web canvas in Animate CC with few buttons. I add code and first button (AN_Jar) work perfectly, but second (Home_Jar) doesn't work.

Here it is:

```
 this.AN_Jar.addEventListener("click", fl_onClick_01.bind(this));

function fl_onClick_01()
{
    this.gotoAndStop(4);
}


this.Home_Jar.addEventListener("click", fl_onClick_home1.bind(this));

function fl_onClick_home1()
{
    this.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

What I'm missing? (I had this website in written in actionscript 3 and it work perfectly well.)

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following code, with two movieclips named on stage with the names in your code, I can see each button being triggered:

```
    this.AN_Jar.addEventListener("click", fl_onClick_01.bind(this));

function fl_onClick_01()
{
    console.log("bt1 hit")
}


this.Home_Jar.addEventListener("click", fl_onClick_home1.bind(this));

function fl_onClick_home1()
{
     console.log("bt2 hit")
}
```

This successfully traces "bt1 hit" and "bt2 hit" when I press each button,is there anything else you can tell us that you are doing?

Comment: Check that both buttons on stage have the unique name you think they do, namely Home_Jar and AN_Jar

Comment: I already solve it with: var that1 = this; this.AN_Jar.addEventListener("click", function () { that1.gotoAndPlay(4); });var that2 = this; this.Home_Jar.addEventListener("click", function () { that2.gotoAndPlay(5); }); - solution by Antti Haapala, in one topic. I don't know, why previous solution doesn't work. (As I said, im very begginer in JS, that I also really don't know, why someone down-vote my question:) Thanks for answer anyway:)